# SyntaxError: how to pass a parameter to a before_action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, syntax-error

I get a SyntaxError on the second line (second `before_action`) below. How can I pass in a variable (`@organization`) that results from the first `before_action` to the second `before_action`?

---

In my controller I call upon the following two before actions:

```
before_action :find_organization
before_action :rights?(@organization)

find_organization
  @organization = Organization.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if @organization == nil
    render json: { errors: "Organization not found" }, status: :bad_request
  end
end
```

The second `before_action` is located in my base controller:

```
private
def rights?(organization)
  unless rights(organization) == "full"   #Uses a helper method
    render json: {errors: "You do not have the right" }, status: :unauthorized
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `before_action` with a block, like this:

```
before_action do
  find_organization
  rights?(@organization)
end
```

Or you could call `rights?` from `find_organization`, if you deem this approach applicable.

Comment: Thanks! What if you would like to add `only: [:show]`? Because if I add this inside the `do... end`, I again get a syntax error.

Comment: More simply, you could just set an instance variable in the first method and then use that variable (if it exists) in the second method.

Comment: to Nick's question about adding the `only: [:show]`, try `before_action only: [:show] do`